# SFMC Reply Mail Management

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am submitting the form for Reply Mail Management but unable to understand how 'Email Reply Address' is different from 'Routing Address for Remaining Replies'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Email Reply Address**: The reply address appears in the From name of your subscriber's email client when the subscriber replies to your
> email. While this information appears in the format of an email
> message, it is not a valid email address on its own. The address
> directs the reply to RMM for processing.

This is basically a fake email address that your subscribers see when they hit reply, eg. `contact@email.company.com`. This fake email will gather all the replies and filter them accordingly to the logic used in your RMM settings.

**Routing Address for Remaining Replies** is a real email inbox that you have access to, where all replies that have not been filtered out by RMM are forwarded to, eg. `inbox@company.com`.

This whole setup is to ensure that all replies that can be handled automatically are filtered and sorted out by RMM, and all remaining replies are forwarded to a real inbox where someone can read them, without disclosing the email address of the real inbox to your subscribers.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_es_reply_mail_management.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Please elaborate on fake email address part. Does contact@email.company.com needs to be a proper email address. If not, how will the email address gather all the replies and filter them?

Comment: In other words, can I just mention any non-existing email address in 'Email Reply Address' and let RMM process the replies internally?

Comment: Yes. The email usually follows the format used in your SAP https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_es_sender_authentication_package.htm&language=en_US

Comment: so if SAP subdomain is email.abc.com, can I use replyxxx@email.abc.com where replyxxx@email.abc.com is not a mailbox

Comment: Yes that’s right you can use that for Email Reply Address

Comment: @AT_SFMC please remember to accept the answer if it helped, thanks!